# What is the translation environment and the execution environment in C, and what's the difference between them?

Tags: c, compilation

What is the translation environment and the execution environment in C, and what's the difference between them?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I have never heard of a "translation environment" in C. Perhaps you mean compilation?

Comment: @BartFriederichs - The OP is asking about an explanation of standardese terms. They do not mean compilation.

Comment: Peter Prinz and Tony Crawford said :C makes a distinction between the environment in which the compiler translates
the source files of a program—the translation environment—and the environment
in which the compiled program is executed, the execution environment.

Comment: See the standard, [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.1).

Comment: @StoryTeller well, I learned today :). Googling "translation environment C" wouldn't give me any of these, only links to automated (natural language) translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **translation environment** refers to the location where the preprocessor, compiler, and linker run to create an executable from one or more source files.  When you run (for example) gcc or Visual Studio, you do so in the translation environment.

The **execution environment** refers to the machine where the compiled and linked code actually runs.

Often, these environments are the same.  This is the case when you compile your code and run your code on the same machine, or on two different machines running the same operating system on the same processor (or processor family).

However, in environments such as embedded systems without an operating system or a small system running an OS but minimal processing capacity, running a compiler on those systems is either impossible or very slow.  In those cases you would run the compiler on a different system but tell it to create executable code that runs on the embedded system.  In that case, the computer that compiles the code can't run the code, but the embedded system can.

This is a case when the translation environment and the execution environment differ.  This is commonly referred to as **cross-compilation**.

For more details, see section 5.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).